# Как правильно написать (может быть ...)?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно написать:

> Фактическая отметка дна траншеи в любой точке не должна превышать проектную и может быть **менее ее** на величину до 100 мм.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Менее ее** и **меньше нее** в Вашем случае не делает фразу менее громоздкой, но Ваша фраза изначально грамматически построена правильно, в соответствии с официально-деловым стилем, так что не волнуйтесь.

Comment: Да, наверное, Вы правы.
Еще раз спасибо за столь оперативный ответ!

Comment: Ох, извините, я новичок на этом сайте, поэтому только сейчас заметила, что мне ответили два разных человека :-)
Поэтому спасибо вам обеим!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, тут лучше будет звучать "меньше". "Менее ее" — четыре Е подряд)))

Answer (score 0):

Фактическая отметка дна траншеи в любой точке не должна превышать проектной более, чем на  100 мм.

Comment: Спасибо! Но вы изменили смысл фразы. 
В вашем варианте: отметка может превышать проектную, но не более чем на 100 мм. 
А в моем: она может превышать проектную на 100 мм, но может быть и меньше нее на 100 мм.
Мне не нравится словосочетание "менее ее". Можно ли его заменить на "меньше нее"?